# why .txt file can't open to read from ftp server ?

Tags: file, ftp

I have manually uploaded a file to a FTP server.
When trying to access it by URL, it is not present.

This is the link: http://fortunemobiletech.net16.net/welcome.txt

Comment: this belongs on serverfault or webmasters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try:
`ftp://` instead of `http://`
with(username password)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the path you uploaded the file to is not the correct one.

Have you placed `welcome.txt` in the `public_html` folder for `fortunemobiletech.net16.net`?

Or if you have access to `net16.net`'s `public_html` folder, try uploading the txt file to `public_html/fortunemobiletech/`.

Comment: thanks to replay me, i have upload the file in home directory of server. but still it not display any thing